# How to modify innerHTML by evaluating an angular expression

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do something like this

```
<div id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    {{item.innerHTML}}
</div>
```

item.innerHTML contains the html that needs to go there, but since it is part of the dom, it is replaced as a string. Is there a way to just have it replace the innerHTML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use ngBindHtml :

http://plnkr.co/edit/n1rLzgEZQoa2tJf0qnVZ?p=preview

in the controller :

```
$scope.content = "<b>this is bold content</b>";
```

html :

```
<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>
```

you'll need the following module :

http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js

Be sure to declare ngSanitize as a module dependancy, for instance :

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ["ngSanitize"]);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not seem to work. This is what I get in the html <div id="item1"> <div ng-bind-html="<p>item1 description</p>" class="ng-binding"></div> </div> . Am I missing something?

Comment: the exemple works as far as i know : http://plnkr.co/edit/n1rLzgEZQoa2tJf0qnVZ?p=preview you must have forgot to do something, also dont put {{}} in ng-bind-html since it is an expression.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I thought you use {{}} to evaluate expressions? http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: @mpm 's answer works! But just as a reminder, don't forget to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application. And also as mpm mentioned, don't forget to declare module dependancy.

Comment: Angular 4: to pass HTML as variable you can use <tag [innerHTML]="passHTML"><tag>