# UI.Bootstrap - wrong text formatting

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, ui.bootstrap

I don't know why on my example when I introduce some a string with html code. it doesn't appear on HTML format.

An example of my job is here:

```
vm_main.test = "Documents" +
        "internet site <b><a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a></b>.";

    vm_main.showModal = {
        mostrarErrores : false,
        showModal : function(jsonError) {
            var options={
                tituloModal: jsonError.titleModal,
                textoPrincipal: jsonError.mainMessage,
                textoBtnAceptar: "Aceptar",
                accionBtnAceptar: "vm_popup.cerrarPopup()",
            };
            commonPopUpService.getDisclaimerGeneric($scope, 'commonPopUpController', options);
        }
    };


    function OnOptionClick() {
        //alert('mostrar popups');
        var jsonError = {
            titleModal : "Privacy Modal",
            mainMessage : "{{vm_main.test}}"
        };
        vm_main.showModal.showModal(jsonError);
    }
```

error image: [image: my error with the string]

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EYDEG5WSmNwxQflsB21T?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngBindHTML :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Here is the solution for your issue :

[How to modify innerHTML by evaluating an angular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242531/how-to-modify-innerhtml-by-evaluating-an-angular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!!!

The solution is get the angular-sanitize.js library, inject into our module and after that use it as follow:

```
<div ng-bind-html="modalObj.textoPrincipal"></div>
```

here you can see it working: [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EYDEG5WSmNwxQflsB21T?p=preview)