# Appending html tag to $scope in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to append html tag to every element in id and show it in text box like `1 x`,`2 x`,`3 x`.(`x` is close button using `&times;`)

I am using the following code.

My html tag

```
<input type="text" id="receiver" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="to" />
```

Angularjs controller

```
$scope.to="";
$scope.id=[1,2,3];
$scope.append = function ($event) {
      $scope.to=$scope.to+id[0]+('<div class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</div>');
}
```

But I am getting following output :

`1 <div class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</div>`,`2<div class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</div>`,`3<div class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</div>`

Can any one help me.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't think its possible to do what you are doing. You cannot have HTML inside an Input tag.

Comment: here i want html tag append to $scope variable

Comment: can you check whether this linke helps you... [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242531/how-to-modify-innerhtml-by-evaluating-an-angular-expression)

Comment: Could you show up your code online.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your solutions:

1. You want to provide an HTML, but this HTML is escaped and treated/displayed as a string in your final output. In order to prevent the HTML from being escaped, you have to use the `ng-bind-html` directive inside of `ng-model`. Don't forget to declare [ngSanitize](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js) as a module dependency.
2. You are trying to include HTML inside an input tag. This won't be possible and most browsers will get this HTML out of the input tag (making it a sibling rather than a child). You have to redesign what you want to do, so the container of `1 x`, `2 x`...is not an `input`.