# Angular do not add closing tags to HTML

Tags: angular

**This is tagged Angular. Please no Angular1 answers.**

My problem is simplified as follows (this is dynamically generated content and the content can vary):

```
<span [innerHTML]="'<p>hello there'"></span>
<span>XXX</span>
<span [innerHTML]="'</p>'"></span>
```

I want XXX to be inside the `<p>` tag. Angular, however is closing the `</p>` tag before the XXX so that I get:

```
<p>hello there</p><span>XXX</span>
```

But I want:

```
<p>hello there<span>XXX</span></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify innerHTML by evaluating an angular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242531/how-to-modify-innerhtml-by-evaluating-an-angular-expression)

Comment: `Angular, however is closing the </p> tag before the XXX` I think there is nothing to do with angular

Comment: This is Angular, the "duplicate" is an angular1 answer!!!

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible using `innerHTML`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Using template quotes will solve your issue in my opinion. Check the Update in my answer. Hope it helped! ;)

Comment: _"Angular, however is closing the </p> tag before the XXX"_ No. The browser does what you tell it to do: it creates a `p` element inside the (first) `span` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with templates and components, if your content is bigger than only `<p><span></span></p>`.

**Example:**

*Component 1:*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component1',
    template: `
        <span>XXX</span>
    `
})
export class myComponent1 {}
```

*Component 2:*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component2',
    template: `
        <p>hello there
            <my-component1></my-component1>
        </p>
    `
})
export class myComponent2 implements OnInit {}
```

Then you just use or `myComponent2` or you use `<my-component2>` somewhere and the output would be:

```
<p>hello there
   <span>XXX</span>
</p>
```

**Update 1:**

For your concrete example *(and for shorter HTML in general)*, this can be an option:

```
public test = `<p>hello there <span>XXX</span></p>`; // In your component

<span [innerHTML]="test"></span> // In your HTML or template
```

Output:

```
hello there XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular has nothing to do with your problem, you are simply putting tags in the wrong way.

Try using `ng-template`

```
<ng-template *ngIf="true">
    <p>hello there
</ng-template>

<span>XXX</span>

<ng-template *ngIf="true">
    </p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This will throw Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

Comment: Yes i agree. So these two need to be rendered at the same time. Individually they arent worth anything. As @PetrAdam said, it will throw error if </p> is present only.