# Split HTML Content and Text from JSON response to use different places in Angular 2 - Typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-services

**HI, I am using Angular 2 for frontend with wordpress rest api backend.**
I am getting a json response from service. But Wp rest api send the content along with HTML tags and images. I am unabale split it and use it in my HTML.
I want use image and text should be at different places. also I need to remove

tag from the content.

service Like:

```
@Injectable()
export class VtkraHomeService {
    private url = 'http://myapplication.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    constructor (private http : Http){

    }

    getFeeds(){
        return this.http
        .get(this.url)
        //.then( (res) => res.json);
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

and ComponentLike:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 

  homefeed: any;
  showLoader = false;

  constructor( private VtkraHomeService: VtkraHomeService ) {  }

getHomeFeeds(){
  this.showLoader = true;
  this.VtkraHomeService
  .getFeeds()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.homefeed = data;
    console.log(this.homefeed);
    this.showLoader = false;
  });
}



  ngOnInit(){
    this.getHomeFeeds()
  }

}
```

I am getting a Json response something like this:

```
    [
       {
          id: 15953,
          date: '2016-10-22T07:55:34',
          title: {
                   rendered: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum',
                   protected: false
                 },
          content: {
                    rendered: '<p><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="w3c" />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <a href="htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris">Link</a></P>',
                   protected: false
                    },
           link: 'htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris',
           type: 'post',
           author: 1
       },
{
          id: 15954,
          date: '2016-10-22T07:55:34',
          title: {
                   rendered: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum',
                   protected: false
                 },
          content: {
                    rendered: '<p><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="w3c" />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <a href="htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris">Link</a></P>',
                   protected: false
                    },
           link: 'htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris',
           type: 'post',
           author: 1
       },
{
          id: 15955,
          date: '2016-10-22T07:55:34',
          title: {
                   rendered: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum',
                   protected: false
                 },
          content: {
                    rendered: '<p><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="w3c" />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <a href="htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris">Link</a></P>',
                   protected: false
                    },
           link: 'htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris',
           type: 'post',
           author: 1
       }
    ];
```

I wanted to get html and text separate from "content (rendered)"

```
content: {
           rendered: '<p><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="w3c" />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <a href="htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris">Link</a></P>',
           protected: false
         },
```

My Html code should be like:

```
<md-list class="home-feed-list">
  <div *ngFor="let item of homefeed">
  <md-list-item routerLink="/Story">
  <img md-list-avatar src="item.content.rendered(image url)" alt="" class="list-avatar">
  <h4>{{item.title.rendered}}</h4>
<p>{{item.content.rendered(remaining text)}}</p>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  </div>
</md-list>
```

Please help me to get it proper: I am beginner in angular2 and Typescript

Comment: Use a `div` instead of `p` and set the innerHTML of the `div`. check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242531/how-to-modify-innerhtml-by-evaluating-an-angular-expression

Comment: I am not looking for render inside a div. I want separate image from response and put it for a thumbnail. Please see the html I am looking for:

Comment: <md-list class="home-feed-list">
  <div *ngFor="let item of homefeed">
  <md-list-item routerLink="/Story">
  <img md-list-avatar src="item.content.rendered(image url)" alt="" class="list-avatar">
  <h4>{{item.title.rendered}}</h4>
<p>{{item.content.rendered(remaining text)}}</p>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  </div>
</md-list>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DOM API to create an object and retrieve the bits and pieces from the rendered string. You can do it in your view-model, after you receive the data from service, and construct your model accordingly in the view-model (i.e. construct `homefeed` containing objects having this image and text property).

A simple example is shown below.

```js
var contentRendered = '<p><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="w3c" />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <a href="htts://www.w3schools.com/css/paris">Link</a></P>'

// create a DOM object from the rendered text
var template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = contentRendered;

// use DOM API to retrieve the data you need from the object
var imgPart = template.content.firstChild.querySelector("img");
var text = template.content.firstChild.innerText;

console.log(imgPart);
console.log(text);
```

Alternatively, you can put this logic in custom AngularJS filter(s), and tweak the rendering accordingly. Though, I am not an AngularJS user, but from [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/m2_y_g/easy-distance-formatter-converter-for-angularjs) it seems that such things can be used for this purpose.

Hope this helps.